# Docker container fail to connect to UiAutomator2 server created by host ADB

Tags: docker, networking, containers, adb, android-uiautomator

I want to containerise my test automation. In my Dockerfile I have set ADB server addess to `ENV ANDROID_ADB_SERVER_ADDRESS "host.docker.internal"`. Therefore, when adb is abl eto list connected devices using `adb devices`. But the issue here is host ADB will create UiAutomator2 on my host which will give `Connection Refused` on y container. Any idea how to resolve this?